# OSerror import language model spacy

Tags: python, spacy

I'm trying to work with spacy . I need to download language model for English, Italian and Spanish.
I can't manually install the model ( because I hope to build a piece of code that is portable ) so i wrote a little function which basically is

```
import os
import spacy    
lang='en'
try:
    mod = lang+'_core_web_sm'
    nlp = spacy.load(mod)
except:
    print('model not present.. downloading and loading')
    cmd = 'python -m spacy download '+ mod
    os.system(cmd)
    nlp = spacy.load(mod)
```

I'm inside a virtualenv with `pip` python3, windows 10.

Model download is fine. This is the output of os.system(cmd)

> Collecting it_core_news_sm==2.2.5 from
>   https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/it_core_news_sm-2.2.5/it_core_news_sm-2.2.5.tar.gz#egg=it_core_news_sm==2.2.5   Downloading
>   https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/it_core_news_sm-2.2.5/it_core_news_sm-2.2.5.tar.gz
>   (14.5MB) Requirement already satisfied: spacy>=2.2.2 in
>   c:\users\marco.fumagalli\classifybusiness\lib\site-packages (from
>   it_core_news_sm==2.2.5) (2.2.4) Requirement already satisfied:
>   srsly<1.1.0,>=1.0.2 in
>   c:\users\marco.fumagalli\classifybusiness\lib\site-packages (from
>   spacy>=2.2.2->it_core_news_sm==2.2.5) (1.0.2) Requirement already
>   satisfied: preshed<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in
>   c:\users\marco.fumagalli\classifybusiness\lib\site-packages (from
>   spacy>=2.2.2->it_core_news_sm==2.2.5) (3.0.2) Requirement already
>   satisfied: wasabi<1.1.0,>=0.4.0 in
>   c:\users\marco.fumagalli\classifybusiness\lib\site-packages (from
>   spacy>=2.2.2->it_core_news_sm==2.2.5) (0.6.0) Requirement already
>   satisfied: murmurhash<1.1.0,>=0.28.0 in
>   c:\users\marco.fumagalli\classifybusiness\lib\site-packages (from
>   spacy>=2.2.2->it_core_news_sm==2.2.5) (1.0.2) Requirement already
>   satisfied: setuptools in
>   c:\users\marco.fumagalli\classifybusiness\lib\site-packages\setuptools-40.8.0-py3.6.egg
>   (from spacy>=2.2.2->it_core_news_sm==2.2.5) (40.8.0) Requirement
>   already satisfied: plac<1.2.0,>=0.9.6 in
>   c:\users\marco.fumagalli\classifybusiness\lib\site-packages (from
>   spacy>=2.2.2->it_core_news_sm==2.2.5) (1.1.3) Requirement already
>   satisfied: catalogue<1.1.0,>=0.0.7 in
>   c:\users\marco.fumagalli\classifybusiness\lib\site-packages (from
>   spacy>=2.2.2->it_core_news_sm==2.2.5) (1.0.0) Requirement already
>   satisfied: tqdm<5.0.0,>=4.38.0 in
>   c:\users\marco.fumagalli\classifybusiness\lib\site-packages (from
>   spacy>=2.2.2->it_core_news_sm==2.2.5) (4.43.0) Requirement already
>   satisfied: cymem<2.1.0,>=2.0.2 in
>   c:\users\marco.fumagalli\classifybusiness\lib\site-packages (from
>   spacy>=2.2.2->it_core_news_sm==2.2.5) (2.0.3) Requirement already
>   satisfied: thinc==7.4.0 in
>   c:\users\marco.fumagalli\classifybusiness\lib\site-packages (from
>   spacy>=2.2.2->it_core_news_sm==2.2.5) (7.4.0) Requirement already
>   satisfied: blis<0.5.0,>=0.4.0 in
>   c:\users\marco.fumagalli\classifybusiness\lib\site-packages (from
>   spacy>=2.2.2->it_core_news_sm==2.2.5) (0.4.1) Requirement already
>   satisfied: requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0 in
>   c:\users\marco.fumagalli\classifybusiness\lib\site-packages (from
>   spacy>=2.2.2->it_core_news_sm==2.2.5) (2.23.0) Requirement already
>   satisfied: numpy>=1.15.0 in
>   c:\users\marco.fumagalli\classifybusiness\lib\site-packages (from
>   spacy>=2.2.2->it_core_news_sm==2.2.5) (1.16.4) Requirement already
>   satisfied: importlib-metadata>=0.20; python_version < "3.8" in
>   c:\users\marco.fumagalli\classifybusiness\lib\site-packages (from
>   catalogue<1.1.0,>=0.0.7->spacy>=2.2.2->it_core_news_sm==2.2.5) (1.5.0)
>   Requirement already satisfied: urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1
>   in c:\users\marco.fumagalli\classifybusiness\lib\site-packages (from
>   requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0->spacy>=2.2.2->it_core_news_sm==2.2.5) (1.23)
>   Requirement already satisfied: chardet<4,>=3.0.2 in
>   c:\users\marco.fumagalli\classifybusiness\lib\site-packages (from
>   requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0->spacy>=2.2.2->it_core_news_sm==2.2.5) (3.0.4)
>   Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in
>   c:\users\marco.fumagalli\classifybusiness\lib\site-packages (from
>   requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0->spacy>=2.2.2->it_core_news_sm==2.2.5)
>   (2019.11.28) Requirement already satisfied: idna<3,>=2.5 in
>   c:\users\marco.fumagalli\classifybusiness\lib\site-packages (from
>   requests<3.0.0,>=2.13.0->spacy>=2.2.2->it_core_news_sm==2.2.5) (2.9)
>   Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in
>   c:\users\marco.fumagalli\classifybusiness\lib\site-packages (from
>   importlib-metadata>=0.20; python_version <
>   "3.8"->catalogue<1.1.0,>=0.0.7->spacy>=2.2.2->it_core_news_sm==2.2.5)
>   (3.1.0) Installing collected packages: it-core-news-sm   Running
>   setup.py install for it-core-news-sm: started
>       Running setup.py install for it-core-news-sm: finished with status 'done' Successfully installed it-core-news-sm-2.2.5 ✔ Download and
>   installation successful You can now load the model via
>   spacy.load('it_core_news_sm')

however when `spacy.load(mod)` is executed:

> OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en_core_web_sm'. It doesn't seem to
>   be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data
>   directory.

Weird because if I do

```
import en_core_web_sm
en_core_web_sm.load()
```

it works.

How can I solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try installing en_core_web_sm through:

```
pip3 install https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.2.5/en_core_web_sm-2.2.5.tar.gz
```